# Fotorama Wordpress Plugin

Tags: fotorama

I have "WordPress 3.7.5" installed and i get the following errors on page load (via element explorer)

```
http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.6/fotorama.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.6/fotorama.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.6/fotorama.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure the files exist?

Comment: It tries to load an external file..it used to work.
The external file might doesn't exist anymore, but i don't know how to change that link.

Comment: Problem solved i added links from here:
http://el.cdnjs.com/libraries/fotorama

to header.php file

thanks a lot nikos.